# Strange characters in AngularJS application

Tags: html, angularjs

I created a simple AngularJS application as url below:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40212784/test/test.html

And it appears to have a strange margin before "123".

When I view it locally, it seems that there are some strange characters before them.
http://f.cl.ly/items/1Z2h3T0k023L2N443V3f/scr002.png

I just started learning AngularJS, any clue will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems the characters are coming from the

```
<meta>
```

tag which on your screenshot locally somehow ended up in the body.

Try moving that up into the

```
<head>
```

section.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.4

Comment: The "test.html" code is [here](http://pastie.org/9370296). I put the <meta> tag in <head> section, but it becomes in <body> section when viewing in browser.